# Is it possible to find global optima for surfaces?

Tags: calculus, machine-learning

I have started studying ML, but my math is not that strong. I've decided to study the math required as I go along.

I want to know whether there is a method that can help find optima of surfaces, just as we can find optima of curves in 2D by using derivatives. If not, please explain why a direct method is not possible for surfaces.

Please suggest resources where I can read more about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "we can find optima of curves in 2D by using derivatives"? Do you mean minimizing a function $f(x)$ by solving $f'(x)=0$? If so then for functions of multiple variables you can do the same using partial derivatives. However in both cases, the equation(s) you obtain may be too hard to solve.

Comment: What do you know about curves? There are two big family of (theoretical) methods: Weierstrass theorem+necessary conditions (like derivative/gradient = 0) and convexity methods. Practically: almost everyone uses stochastic gradient descent, and this converges to local optima only.

Comment: @Rahul ,Yes i meant  by solving f'(x)=0. Could you give an example where it becomes difficult to solve resulting equations.

Comment: @dcolazin , as I said i know very little about curves. I just assumed that since there are 3D graphing software, there should be some method they implement to graph a surface and therefore some way of finding minima without using gradient descent.

Comment: @void $x^{2019} -x^{2018} +2x^{512} + 6x^{28} - 4x^5 +  x^2 - x + 1 = 0$